# Retrieving values matching the same ID with perl

Tags: perl, hash

This is a simple problem but cannot find any working solution for it. I have 2 files and the first file holds all the ID that I am interested in, for example "tomato", "cucumber", but also the ones I am not interested in, which hold no value in the second file. The second file has the following data structure

```
tomato    red

tomato    round

tomato    sweet

cucumber    green

cucumber    bitter

cucumber    watery
```

What I need to get is a file containing all the IDs with all the matching values from the second file, everything tab-seperated, like this:

```
tomato    red    round    sweet

cucumber    green    bitter    watery
```

What I did so far is create a hash out of the IDs in the first file:

```
 while (<FILE>) {  
     chomp;  
     @records = split "\t", $_; 
     {%hash = map { $records[0] => 1 } @records};
 }
```

And this for the second file:

```
  while (<FILE2>) {
      chomp;
      @records2 = split "\t", $_; 
      $key, $value = $records2[0], $records2[1];
      $data{$key} = join("\t", $value);
  }

 close FILE;

 foreach my $key ( keys %data )
 {
     print OUT "$key\t$data{$key}\n"
     if exists $hash{$key} 
 }
```

Would be grateful for some simple solution for combining all the values matching the same ID! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for th first file:

```
while (<FILE>) {  
    chomp;  
    @records = split "\t", $_; 
    $hash{$records[0]} = 1;
}
```

and for the second:

```
while (<FILE2>) {
    chomp;
    @records2 = split "\t", $_;
    ($key,$value) = @records2;
    $data{$key} = [] unless exists $data{$key};
    push @{$data{$key}}, $value;
}
close FILE;

foreach my $key ( keys %data ) {
    print OUT $key."\t".join("\t", @{$data{$key}})."\n" if exists $hash{$key};
}
```

Comment: Yep. It's also worth a trip to `perldoc perldsc` which describes data structures in Perl, including the array of hashes used above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, CyberDem0n, it works as it should :). Thanks guys, I was not familiar with creating arrays of hashes before, will look it up now!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what is needed

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  $data{$1} = {} if /([^\t]+)/;
}

open $fh, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  $data{$1}{$2}++ if /^(.+?)\t(.+?)$/ and exists $data{$1};
}

while ( my ($key, $values) = each %data) {
  print join("\t", $key, keys %$values), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
tomato  sweet round red
cucumber  green watery  bitter
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easier if you read the data mapping first.

Also, if you are using Perl, you should consider from the get-go leveraging one its main strengths - CPAN libraries. For example, the reading in of the file is as simple as `read_file()` from `File::Slurp`; instead of having to open/close the file yourself and then run a while(<>) loop.

```
use File::Slurp;
my %data;

my @data_lines = File::Slurp::read_file($filename2);
chomp(@data_lines);
foreach my $line (@data_lines) { # Improved version from CyberDem0n's answer
    my ($key, $value) = split("\t", $line);
    $data{$key} ||= []; # Make sure it's an array reference if first time
    push @{ $data{$key} }, $value;
}

my @id_lines = File::Slurp::read_file($filename1);
chomp(@id_lines);
foreach my $id (@id_lines) {
    print join("\t", ( $id, @{ $data{$id} } ) )."\n";
}
```

A slightly more hacky but a bit shorter code adds the ID to the list of values in the data hash from the get go:

```
my @data_lines = File::Slurp::read_file($filename2);
chomp(@data_lines);
foreach my $line (@data_lines) { # Improved version from CyberDem0n's answer
    my ($key, $value) = split("\t", $line);
    $data{$key} ||= [ $id ]; # Add the ID for printing
    push @{ $data{$key} }, $value;
}

my @id_lines = File::Slurp::read_file($filename1);
chomp(@id_lines);
foreach my $id (@id_lines) {
    print join("\t", @{ $data{$id} } ) ."\n"; # ID already in %data!
}
```